# Different images from Webcam with OpenCV 4.20 builds (MSVC 2019 (good image) and MinGW(weird image))

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw

I was using OpenCV 4.2.0 on Microsoft Studio which I downloaded the pre compiled version from the official repository, it was working fine. Then I decided to move to MinGW and compiled the source code of the same version. Everything seemed to work but when I tested the video capture on MinGW, I am getting this weird effect which don't happen with my Microsoft Studio. Look at the difference, the picture on the left is from MinGW and the right one is MSCV2019, with the same camera parameters and taken at the same time.

[image: Left MinGW / Right MSCV2019]

Anything I can rid of this undesired effect? I tested the input image on other webcam softwares and it doesn't seen to happen.

Comment: set apiPreference (VideoCapture argument) to something specific, then compare again. try DSHOW, MSMF, and FFMPEG

Comment: I tested FFMPEG, GSTREAMER, INTEL_MFX, MSMF, DSHOW, CV_IMAGES, MJPEG. MSVC seems to use MSMF by default and it doesn't work with MinGW. DSHOW while much slower seemed to work on both and seemed to solve my problem. By any chance, do happen to know how can I make MSMF work on MinGW? The diference is 1 FPS to 15 FPS.

Comment: I think that could be an issue of cmake variables. look at `cv::getBuildInformation()` result to see what you actually built it with. run cmake-gui and investigate the choices available to you.